# imap_open() in PHP is not handling UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, imap

I am using the PHP imap functions to read a mailbox that receives UTF-8 encoded plain text email (generated by another server).  Accented characters are replaced with question mark (?).  Below is my code and following that are two attempts at fixing it.  How do I fix the problem? I have no control over the server that generates the messages, but they claim they are encoded UTF-8. mb_detect_encoding says the imap_body function is returning an ASCII string, but I've found mb_detect_encoding to be somewhat buggy in the past.

```
$connection = imap_open( '{localhost:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 0, 1 );
$result = imap_search( $connection, 'UNSEEN' );
if ( $result )
    {
    foreach ( $result as $msgno )
        {
        $body = imap_body( $connection, $msgno );

        // ... (code to process the message) ...

        imap_mail_move( $connection, "$msgno:$msgno", 'INBOX.processed' );
        }

    imap_expunge( $connection );
    imap_close( $connection );
        }
    }
```

I tried the following to convert to UTF-8, even though the message was already UTF-8:

```
$current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $body, 'auto' ); // Returns "ASCII"
$body = mb_convert_encoding( $body, $current_encoding, 'UTF-8' );
```

I also tried:

```
$body = mb_convert_encoding( $body, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8' );
```

Comment: You should probably not try to detect the encoding, but look at the mail instead and use what has been stated as the used encoding there.

Comment: Emails are almost always encoded in Quoted Printable or Base64 encoding when they are in base64.  You'll need to undo the TRANSFER-ENCODING before doing character set encoding.

Comment: I looked at the encoding in the header: Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT
Content-type: text/plain; CHARSET=US-ASCII. I'll try and contact the people generating the message and see if they will fix it.

Comment: They are probably not sending 7-bit safe email.

Comment: Also, start with Thunderbird. If it can't render the emails, you're unlikely to be able to.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the body of the email

```
$body = imap_body( $connection, $msgno );
```

Decode the Message Body by using code below

```
$body = utf8_decode(imap_utf8($body));
```

Use the same logic for $subject also..

For more details Refer [imap_utf8](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: I got hold of the people generating the email and they made the following header changes:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
```

That solved it. My PHP program now sees the UTF-8 characters.